# Why does my new app override the old version on my dev device, and how can I make them separate?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I have opened a can of worms by using an old pre-built project as the foundation for a new one.

When I open the old project in the simulator or on a device, it uses images and settings from the new app that aren't even referenced or included in that original project. Even worse, when I download the old app from the app store, it overrides my new app on the test device. The device sees the two different apps as the same project still.

How can I make these apps completely separate from one another?

Comment: Make sure you are using a different bundle id for the two apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before running your application, remove the older one from your phone/simulator**

[image]

And if this is not an update for the old app, Then USE **A DIFFERENT BUNDLE IDENTIFIER**.

Also, before you run the app from Xcode, **CLEAN**, **BUILD** then **RUN**.

Comment: what is the image for? the image is just confusing IMO :D

Comment: Even-though the bundle identifier is the same, If we delete the app before running it from the xCode, old one does not mix with the new app. Therefore deleting the old app is important. Seeing an image like this remember the deletion of the app at once, that's why I used it.

Comment: Where is the 'Clean' option located?

Comment: Under Product Menu, or use the shortcut: Shift+cmd+K

Answer (score 0):

iOS usees the **bundle identifier** to uniquely identify an app. the display name is of no importance for the os.